# WebStorm and Firefox - sync

Tags: firefox, browser, synchronization, webstorm

I am working on WebStorm and Chrome. It allows me to live coding. 
I would like to change Chrome to Firefox, because it has not got problems with set mobile view.

So, how can I set live coding with WebStorm and Firefox?

I want to write code and see changes on screen without saving. Any tips?

Comment: WebStorm's Live Edit plugin works with **Chrome only**. It has to be some 3rd party solution (like Live Reload etc) and for this you will have to click "Save" in WebStorm to see the changes.

Comment: Ok, so I may use Browsersync with Firefox, right? How to do this with Webstorm?

Answer (score 1):

Live Edit in FireFox is not currently supported, please vote for [WEB-1805](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1805).
WebStorm doesn't provide integration with available third-party solutions, but you can still use Browsersync, etc. - start it in terminal or using Gulp/Grunt file, open your application URL in FireFox, hit Save All in WebStorm to get edited files saved - page will be updated